# Store file contents of .npz file in array

Tags: python, arrays, glob

I have multiple .npz files and I am accessing each file by using `glob.glob`. In each of these .npz file I have a file titled `bbox` which contains 4 array values. I would like to store each `bbox` in one large array however when running line 4 I am getting this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`. Is there another way around what I need to accomplish?

```
import glob 

entries = glob.glob('BIWILANDMARKS/*/*.npz', recursive=True)
print("Landmarks size: ",len(entries))

d = dict(zip(("bbox".format(k) for k in entries), (entries[k] for k in entries)))
print(d)
```

Link for one .npz file [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1s2nfPvvKyZynPgMlRbGE_ZKd754S_Bcr?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is `"bbox".format(k)` supposed to do?

Comment: `entries[k] for k in entries` this makes little sense if `entries` is a list, did you mean just `entries`?

Comment: All of the .npz files I have accessed through `glob.glob`

Comment: @mkrieger1 I tried it and only printed the following `{'bbox': 'BIWILANDMARKS\\9\\frame_00884_info.npz'}`

Comment: What exactly did you expect to get instead?

Comment: Can you show an actual example?

Comment: @mkrieger1 When I `print(d)` I was expecting to have the array values listed from each 'bbox' in each .npz file. When I say array value, each 'bbox' has values of this sort `[23 45 78 100]` and so I would like to have each of these arrays listed under each other in one big array

Comment: @mkrieger1 `data = np.load('BIWILANDMARKS/1/frame_00004_info.npz')
print(data['bbox'])` This way I am loading the first file. It prints out `[299 237  87  84]`. I would like to save that array and each other array from each .npz file in one array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this part `(entries[k] for k in entries)` where it expects k to be index i.e., int type but it is actually an item from the `entries` array.

More specifically, you are passing an item of `entries` array as an index to the `entries` array.

For the given file in the link, we can write as below

```
import glob 
import numpy as np

entries = glob.glob('frame_*_info.npz', recursive=True)
print("Landmarks size: ",len(entries))

d = {f'bbox[{k}]':np.load(entries[k])['bbox'] for k in range(len(entries))}
print(d)
```

the output is,

```
Landmarks size:  2
{'bbox[0]': array([299, 237,  87,  84]),
 'bbox[1]': array([299, 236,  86,  84])}
```

Think, this is what you expect!

Comment: I tried your solution however when I `print(d)` all I got was: `{'bbox': 'BIWILANDMARKS\\24\\frame_00622_info.npz'}` I am expecting to have the the values of 'bbox', which contains 4 array values, listed. For instance 'bbox[0]' would have `[23 45 78 100]` and same goes for `bbox[1], bbox[2]..` I would like to have them listed under each other

Comment: Can you give me more details like, what does the `.npz` file contains?

Comment: The `.npz` file contains three files one of them being `bbox`. The following code prints the contents of the first file only `data = np.load('BIWILANDMARKS/1/frame_00004_info.npz') print(data['bbox'])` and from it I get `[299 237  87  84]`. I want to save that array and all other arrays like it from other `.npz` files in one large array.

Comment: I added a Gdrive link for 2 .npz files

Comment: I have edited as per your need.

Comment: Thats a nice way of obtaining the values, cheers

Comment: Please accept the answer if satisfied :P

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

- `"bbox".format(k)` is just always the string `"bbox"`, therefore the dictionary created by `dict(zip(("bbox".format(k) for k in ...), ...))` will only have 1 entry, with the key `"bbox"`.
- If `entries` is a list of strings (returned by `glob`), then `entries[k] for k in entries` gives the error you have observed, because `k` is one of those strings and can't be used as an index.

From the explanations you gave in the comments it seems you wanted to do this:

```
d = {}
for filename in entries:
    data = np.load(filename)
    d[filename] = data['bbox']
```

Or the same as a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {filename: np.load(filename)['bbox'] for filename in entries}
```

However, it's not quite clear to me if you really wanted to use the filename as key in the dictionary, or something different.

Comment: No I did not require the filename to be used as well. But thank you the following worked as required: `for filename in entries[0:1]:
    d = np.load(filename)['bbox'] 
` I was wondering if there would be a way I can do it as a one liner?

Answer (score 0):

Both Answers provided were great solutions. However if anyone should require to obtain ONLY the array values. One can implement it the following way:

```
import glob 

entries = glob.glob('BIWILANDMARKS/*/*.npz', recursive=True)
print("Landmarks size: ",len(entries))

file = []
for f in entries:     
    data = np.load(f)['bbox']
    file.append(data)
```

If you print out the first ten values `print(file)` you obtain the following:
`[array([299, 237,  87,  84]), array([299, 236,  86,  84]), array([299, 236,  86,  85]), array([300, 237,  87,  85]), array([300, 237,  87,  84]), array([300, 237,  87,  85]), array([300, 237,  86,  84]), array([300, 236,  87,  85]), array([300, 237,  87,  84]), array([300, 236,  87,  85])]`

This way I can call any value from any array. For instance: I require second value from second array: `print(file[1][1])` which prints out `236`